# Integrating Admob to the Top/ Bottom of the Layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-relativelayout

Am trying to integrate the Admob unit into either the Top or Bottom of the layout but as soon as I put in my Admob code the apk generated will fail miserably when I run it. Could anyone please lend me a hand?

Thanks

Admob Code

```
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, zzzzzzzzzzzz"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Layout Code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/item_select" >


    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"      
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView     
            android:id="@+id/list_image"   
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/angry"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="@string/Testing"
        android:textColor="#080808"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_rating" />

</RelativeLayout>
```